Why does this PDA qualify as deterministic if multiple transitions are possible after reading a symbol?
In the book Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation (3rd ed.) by Hopcroft, Ullman, and Motwani, a deterministic PDA (DPDA) is defined as follows:

A PDA $ P = (Q, \Sigma, \Gamma, \delta, q_0, Z_0, F) $ is deterministic if and only if the following conditions are met:

$ \delta(q, a, X) $ has at most one member for any $ q \in Q $, $ a \in \Sigma $ or $ a = \epsilon $, and $ X \in \Gamma $.
If $ \delta(q, a, X) $ is nonempty for some $ a \in \Sigma $, then $ \delta(q, \epsilon, X) $ must be empty.


Now consider the following PDA:

From the PDA's transition rules, it satisfies both conditions of being a DPDA:

Each configuration of state, input symbol, and stack top has at most one transition.
No $\epsilon$-transition is available if a transition for a regular input symbol is defined.

However, after reading input $ a $:

The PDA transitions to state $ q_1 $ and pushes $ X $ onto the stack.
From $ q_1 $, there is an $\epsilon$-transition to $ q_2 $, which pops $ X $ from the stack, or the PDA can remain in $ q_1 $.

My question is:

Isn't the PDA supposed to be in one state at any given moment since it is deterministic?
How can I determine which state the PDA is in after reading $ a $?
How do I decide whether $ a $ is accepted or not in this context?


Consider what happens to your example if there's the rest of DPDA to interact with and at least one more symbol in the input
You'll find that PDA can't remain in $q_1$ because it'll get *stuck* - in $q_1$ it can't take any input, because it has valid $\epsilon$-transition for its state+stacktop and DPDA definition requires no input processing in that case.
Only the path, that walked the epsilon "road" to the end, can continue processing inputs
On the other hand, if you don't track from-input-to-input, but instead transition-to-transition, you'll find that every Global State (state+stack+unused_input) has only 1 next Global State to transition to (so, determinism) and your whole example is a misunderstanding of what is happening at the same time and what isn't.

It's probably my transition-primary view showing, but I genuinely don't see the problem
Just because PDA transitioned through some states, doesn't mean its whole path gets counted as "next states".
After reading $a$ it passed through several states, but ended up in $q_2$
$q_2$ isn't accepting, thus it wasn't accepted

I think generally assumed intuition for input-based perspective (that allows it to coincide with transition-based view) is to assume that acceptance/non-acceptance gets decided *after* reading end-of-input symbol
That way you can't observe states "in processing", when automata is manipulating its stack and hasn't decided that it's ready (for input) yet

I was also trying for some hours to come up with intuition why in input-oriented view $\epsilon$-transition in DPDA becomes obligatory, while in $\epsilon$-NFA it's "optional" (which I guessed where your confusion comes from) - and best I can think of is that NFA decides non-deterministically whether to follow $\epsilon$-transition or to "accept input", while DPDA definition ensures that only one of those is possible at any moment.

You can also play around with the concept of "$\epsilon$-DFA" (e.g. DPDA with limited relevant stack, where each (state, finite_stack) gets encoded into $\epsilon$-DFA state), which is DFA like you expect, but some states can instead have only $\epsilon$-transition.
Obviously these $\epsilon$-states would get optimized out and are kinda irrelevant (and thus intuitively probably shouldn't affect acceptance/non-acceptance), but you can only proceed from them by walking the epsilons
In "input-to-input" worldview you do travel through many of the $\epsilon$-states to get to the one not-epsilon one, but do you really have to call all all of them as "possible states after reading a symbol"?

Your observations are correct. The given PDA is deterministic: for any configuration (state+tape symbol+top of stack) there is at most one other next configuration. As your example shows the DPDA can still do computations on $\varepsilon$ after reading its input.
Such computations may even involve additional popping and pushing, they may be infinite, and worst of all, we may actually find an accepting state during that $\varepsilon$-computation.
This is indeed problematic in proofs for DPDA, I give an example of this.
The problem also occurs with $\varepsilon$-computations in between reading letters. In some cases it is hard to decide whether the DPDA will in fact read the next letter, or will go off in an infinite computation. As you might know DPDA are closed under complement. That means infinite computations at the end might be accepting if we happen to stumble upon an accepting state, and infinite computations in between are not-accepting, as we are required to read the full input. For the complement construction this has to be reversed. Hence the complement construction for DPDA is much more involved than that for deterministic finite automata: we cannot just swap accepting and non-accepting states.
